# Python 3 - Sockets with select.select() - detecting loss of connection

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, tcp

I've got a Python 3 server script which runs a TCP socket server, detecting and responding to incoming data using select.select()

I'm using select.select() to handle multiple connections without threading and the server is mainly reactive (only waits for data and responds to that). It keeps a dictionary for each connection and parameters of the device at the other end; each device's entry is deleted upon its connection being closed.

My problem is my clients will sometimes lose connection without actually closing the TCP socket, I can't work out how to catch or create a timeout to close the sockets and remove old connections from the dictionary.

Is there a good way to do this?

Here's a simplified copy of the script:

```
host = '192.168.0.252'
port = 9989
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server.bind((host,port))
server.listen(16)
socks = [server]
devices = {}

while True:
  readable,writable,exceptionavailable = select.select(socks,[],[])
  for s in readable:
    if(s == server):
      client, address = server.accept()
      socks.append(client)
    else:
      try: data = s.recv(1024)
      except ConnectionResetError: data = 0

      if data:
        print(data) # Would append device to "devices" dictionary
      else:
        s.close()
        socks.remove(s)
        del(devices[did]) # did is the ID that needs deleting from dictionary
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest looking into the `SO_KEEPALIVE` options and related options. Using these options on the socket will enable use of keep alive probes to check if the connection was closed without warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Updated with better code per @Daniel's comment.

Let's say you want to close a connection if you haven't read from it in X seconds. Then you have to:

1. For each socket keep track of the last time you read from it.
2. Each time select returns update the last read time and close the connections which have timed-out.

In this code a connection's timeout is set to 300 seconds.

```
lastread = {} # a dictionary with sockets as keys
...

readable,_,_ = select.select(socks,[],[], 60)
now = time()
for s in readable:
  ... read from the socket s and process input ...
  lastread[s] = now
closed = []
for s in lastread:
  if s not in readable and now - lastread[s] > 300:
    ... close connection ...
    closed.append(s)
for s in closed: del lastread[s]
```

Notes:

1. The timeout passed to `select` (60 in this case) doesn't have much to do with the timeout for a connection. It just says that you want control handed back to you after at most 60 seconds.
2. Be sure to initialize `lastread[s]` when you create the socket `s` and delete the key when you close the connection.

Some more resources:

- A tutorial on using `select` with a timeout [(link)](http://pymotw.com/2/select/)
- An article which discusses the dropped TCP connection problem and some other solutions: [(link)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37490/Detection-of-Half-Open-Dropped-TCP-IP-Socket-Conne)

Comment: Works great! Thanks.
I added a minor modification to use `now = int(time.perf_counter())` so as to make the time independent from changes to the system clock (NTP updates or manual time update or something) and also to attempt sending a "ping" a few times before finally cutting the connection just in case that prompts the other end to send something (which I will add to the clients who may need it).

Comment: How does this work? You can't del a key from a list you are currently iterating over?

Comment: You're right. It works because that last part of that code is actually in a loop, so eventually all keys of `lastread` are processed. I'll update the code with a better solution.